# Json properties with different types

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an object, that deserialized from json like that.
One of the json property maybe with two different types (that the reason of enum)

```
enum CarValues: Codable { // this enum to recognize,what type of value in array we need
    case withParam(ValuesWithParam)
    case withoutParam(ValuesWithoutParam)

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        switch self {
        case .withParam(let v): try container.encode(v)
        case .withoutParam(let v): try container.encode(v)
        }
    }

    func returnId() -> Int?{
        switch self {
        case .withParam(let v):
            return v.params[0].id
        default :
            return nil
        }
    }

    func initValue(value: String){

        switch self {
        case .withParam (var v):
            v.params[0].setValue(valueToAdd: value)
        default:
            _ = ""
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let value = try decoder.singleValueContainer()

        if let v = try? value.decode(ValuesWithParam.self) {
            self = .withParam(v)
            return
        } else if let v = try? value.decode(ValuesWithoutParam.self) {
            self = .withoutParam(v)
            return
        }

        throw Values.ParseError.notRecognizedType(value)
    }

    enum ParseError: Error {
        case notRecognizedType(Any)
    }
}

struct ValuesWithParam: Decodable, Encodable{
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var params: [Car]

}

struct ValuesWithoutParam: Decodable, Encodable{
    var id: Int
    var title: String
}
```

I wanna change some property of this object, how can I do this?
I try to do this in function `initValue`, but (var v) - only the copy of basic object.

Comment: What object do you want to change, I don't follow? And why not make `params` optional and have only one struct?

Comment: My bad, something stuck in my head. Optional type (without enum, on deserialization) of course solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `initValue` function to this:

```
mutating func initValue(value: String){
    if case .withParam (var v) = self {
        v.params[0].setValue(valueToAdd: value)
        self = .withParam(v)
    }
}
```

To update your `enum` value you have to replace it, and it requires `mutating` function to do so.

Also, I've replaced `switch` with only one `case` handled with `if case`.

Comment: Hi @user28434, if you use `v.params[0]` and `params` comes empty or `nil` you get crash. You should use like this: `v.params.first?.setValue(valueToAdd: value)`. Enjoy.

Comment: @EmreCiftci, I know, but that part was in original code, so I left it as it is.